# Matrix diagonalization after a completely positive transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

I have a hermitian matrix $A$ which can be diagonalized:
$$A=UDU^+,$$
where U is the unitary matrix and D is the diagonal matrix.
Next, I have a completely positive transformation over it, which is introduced with the set of matrices $\{L_j\}$ so that
$$\tilde{A}=\sum_j{L_jAL_j^+},$$
where $\tilde{A}$ is again the hermitian matrix with diagonalization:
$$\tilde{A}=\tilde{U}\tilde{D}\tilde{U}^+.$$
The question is: can $\tilde{U}$ and $\tilde{D}$ be somehow expressed via $U$, $D$ and $\{L_j\}$?

Comment: Of course: from $U$ and $D$ you compute $A$, with that and the $L_j$ you get $\widetilde{A}$, and from that you get (non-uniquely, of course) $\widetilde{D}$ and $\widetilde{U}$.  But if you want a much simpler way than that, it's rather unlikely.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I would like to get an analytical result but event in the case of 2x2 matrix it seems to be hardly resolvable, so I'm looking for some convinient matrix expression